# OpenGL: Buffer Objects/Shaders going out of scope

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and I have a problem.

I know that all the memory is allocated onto the GPU by OpenGL, so technically scope shouldn't be an issue? However, when I try to do this:

```
int SetUpVertexShader(){
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    //BUILD AND COMPILE SHADER
    //VERTEX SHADER
    GLuint vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    //snip - code to compile shader, etc etc
    }


};

int SetUpFragmentShaderandLink(){
    //BUILD AND COMPILE SHADER
    //FRAGMENT SHADER
    GLint success;
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    //snip - code to compile shader, etc etc

};

int linkShaders(){
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader); //this line has complaints saying vertexShader is an undeclared identifier
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader); // this line also has complaints saying fragmentShader is an undeclared identifier
    //the rest of the lines all have undeclared identifier complaints
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    //check linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
};
```

then once I get to the linking shaders and program function linkShaders, I get complaints saying that the vertex shader and fragment shader are out of scope (more specifically, I get told that those two are "undeclared identifiers"). If these are being allocated on the GPU, instead of on the stack, then why am I being told they are going out of scope? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Files are allocated on a disk, but if you declare `FILE* foo = fopen ("foo.txt", "w")` and then try to use `foo` outside of its scope, you get an error. Does it remind you of something?

Comment: Please show the declarations/definitions of `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader` as used by `linkShaders` (hint: the definitions you show are local to `SetUpVertexShader` and `SetUpFragmentShaderandLink` respectively).

Comment: @n.m. Can you explain that further?

Comment: `FILE* foo` is a file handle. `GLuint fragmentShader` is a shader handle. Both are normal C variables that obey normal scope rules. Things they stand for, a file and a shader, are not C objects, they have nothing to do with scope rules or anything else in the C language. To recap, shaders are allocated on the GPU, their handles are not. Handles are normal C objects. Your program only sees handles, not shaders themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables need to be in scope to use them (this is true regardless of OpenGL involved or not).

What `glCreateShader` and `glCreateProgram` return and `glAttachShader` and `glLinkProgram` use are *handles* (unique identifiers for specific purposes) to OpenGL objects. Make sure to save them in a place where you can access them when you need to supply them to other OpenGL calls (especially to cleanup functions if you no longer need the resources you initially requested).

Comment: So does that mean that things like GLuint vertexShader are handles?

Comment: Yes, `vertexShader`is a _handle_ to an object handled internally by OpenGL and can be manipulated via OpenGL calls where it is supplied.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is not the memory itself being out of scope, as GPU memory is following a Heap-Pattern, while variables goong  out of scope can only happen in a Stack-Pattern.

The issue is that the Pointer to this memory, which is stored in CPU Memory, is located on the stack and going out of scope. So you simply have to declare your GLuint Pointers outside the function body.

Comment: What you wrote there is factually inaccurate and misleading. It's more confusing than helpful. See @n.m.'s comment above for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: @datenwolf Could you explain where the inaccuaricy lies? It is for sure correct tough, and does not rely on totally unrelated analogies as the comment above, but actually gives the correct names for the issues for further research and understanding, as well as a paraphrased solution, instead of asking "does that remember you of something?". So I would really like to know why this deserves a downvote, and why you don't give a better alternative answer instead. Tl;dr: What is the issue exactly??

Comment: First inaccuracy: Memory doesn't have scope. Symbols have. There is no such thing as a "heap **pattern**" in memory management. Certain operating systems and/or runtime environments define the concept of "heap memory" in an address space, but that's only something that's strictly defined. Also in C/C++ there's no "heap" at all. There is *static* *automatic* and *dynamic* storage. And last but not least, OpenGL texture and buffer names/IDs *are __not__* pointers, they're handles! A OpenGL texture or buffer ID does *not* even refer to a particular memory location at all.

Comment: @datenwolf I am afraid, this is simply wrong. Dynamic storage is commonly referred to as "Heap allocation", "Heap memory pattern" or "Heap pattern", while static automatic storage is commonly refered to as "Stack allocation", "Stack memory pattern" or "Stack pattern". Also, OpenGL handles, just as any other arbitrary handle, can be viewed as memory pointers in a certain memory space, which here is the OpenGL interface and does not necessarily have to be physical adresses. For further explanation, I will be happy to give some reference links to some lecture books.

Comment: Please show me where in the C language standard (freely accessible draft here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) the word "heap" shows up. Then repeat this for the POSIX standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Take all the time you need. *heap memory* is a very vague term, and as far as I know Microsoft Windows is the only OS that explicitly uses the term "heap" at all.

Comment: @datenwolf Indeed, as I said this is what it is commonly referred to as, as I am sure you know. If it helps, I can edit that minor naming difference, that should make it a perfectly valid answer then, right?

Comment: There's still the issue that you refer to OpenGL object names / handles (GLuint values) as *pointers*. They're not. You can not dereference a object handle. In fact a OpenGL object name does not even refer to a particular region of memory at all. There may be between zero to several memory regions associated with a single particular OpenGL object at any moment. For example in the sequence `glBindTexture(texid); for(…){ glTexSubImage(…); glDrawElements(…); } glFinish();` every time glTexSubImage is called an additional memory region is associated to that single name.

Comment: @datenwolf Imprecise of mine indeed, I do not see through OpenGL that well, sadly. Does this make the answer wrong (to the point it deserves a downvote), considering I did give the correct solution just because of a naming error? Punishing me for helping? Thanks SO.

Comment: The issue at hand with this question has nothing to do with pointers, memory, or scopes at all. The error OP gets because certain symbols are not within the scope of where the error happens. However merely pulling those symbols into the scope (by whatever means, be it by making them class members, or by implementing a global lookup dictionary, or by … you name it) is not going to address the actual problem: The lack of understanding by OP, that what has to be done is to pass the **values** created by `glCreateShader` calls to `glAttachShader`; it's not about the memory or symbol scope.

Comment: @datenwolf It does address the problem with the code, tough. That is the "actual problem" imho.